# Is there a way to predict infix function behavior for partially applied functions in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax, currying, partial-application

I have two functions--

```
partialSubtractionWith5 :: (Num a) => a -> a
partialSubtractionWith5 = (subtract 5)
```

and

```
partialSubtractionWith5' :: (Num a) => a-> a
partialSubtractionwith5' = (`subtract` 5)
```

calling `partialSubtractionWith5 x` returns the equivalent of *x* - 5, while calling `partialSubtractionWith5' x` returns the equivalent of 5 - *x*.

In [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#curried-functions), Lipovača defines the following function--

```
isUpperAlphanum :: Char -> Bool
isUpperAlphanum = (`elem` ['A'..'B'])
```

Which (based on my experiments with `subtract`) I would have thought would have behaved like so when called as `isUpperAlphanum 'some char'`:

```
Prelude> ['A'..'B'] `elem` 'some char'
False
```

Clearly, this is not the case.  But why? And is there a way to predict what functions will reverse their arguments when partially applied?

Comment: I find `subtract` is pretty counter-intuitive, so I generally avoid it.

Comment: It is a little weird, but if you read `subtract x y` like **subtract x _from_  y** then it makes perfect sense.

Comment: It makes most sense to me when mapping, e.g. `map (subtract 5) [1..10]` as opposed to `map (+(-5)) [1..10]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no contradiction, it's just that `subtract = flip (-)`. I.e.

```
partialSubtractionWith5' x ≡ (`subtract` 5) x
                           ≡ x `subtract` 5
                           ≡ 5 - x
```

and, likewise,

```
isUpperAlphanum '□' ≡ '□' `elem` ['A'..'B']
```

OTOH,

```
partialSubtractionWith5 x ≡ (subtract 5) x
                          ≡ (5`subtract`) x
                          ≡ 5 `subtract` x
                          ≡ x - 5
```